# iOS 7 UIButton alignment

Tags: ios, uibutton, alignment, badge

I'm trying to make custom badge. For that I make subclass of UIButton and remake - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect like this:

```
    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        [self setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = rect.size.width / 2;
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        self.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
        self.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    }
```

And everything is good except alignment. It is a little upper than it should be. Looks like this: [image]

What to do?

Comment: Try adding line [self.titleLabel setCenter:self.center];

Comment: @maria: You want that badge to be shown in tab of tab bar controller?


@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString *badgeValue;    // default is nil It's a property of tabbar item

Comment: I tried the exact code, and it's working perfectly.

Comment: You could use this library. its pretty neat for badges.. [iOS Badges](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSCustomBadge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is badge I need: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSCustomBadge . Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

`@property(nonatomic)        NSTextAlignment    textAlignment;`
 `// default is NSTextAlignmentLeft`

It's an attribute of `UILabel`.